# How to install Ubuntu in VMware workstation?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-workstation, ubuntu-14.04, vmware-player, vmware-server

I want to install Ubuntu in my VMware workstation.

My laptop has Windows 7 32 bit. Can I install Ubuntu 64 bit in the VMware workstation or can I install a 32 bit version only?

Sometimes while installing the Ubuntu ISO, if my laptop is on wifi it will install the server edition instead of the desktop edition.

Comment: it is very strange that wifi setup will change the ditribution of ubuntu you are installing.

Comment: You can if your CPU supports hardware virtualization.  So the answer to this question is: *it depends*

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how much virtual memory you want to allocate to the Ubuntu guest OS. If you have enough physical memory to allocate 4GB of RAM or more to the guest OS, then you should install the 64-bit version. Since your laptop probably doesn't have 8GB RAM to allocate between the host OS and the guest OS, you should probably install the 32-bit version of Ubuntu. To install the Ubuntu desktop, be sure that you have downloaded the iso file for [Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), not the iso file for Ubuntu Server.

To determine whether your computer's hardware will support installing a 64-bit guest OS on a 32-bit host OS do as follows:

1. Find the model number of your CPU and search for the specifications of that model number CPU. You can find the specifications of an Intel CPU by searching for `ARK Intel CPU-model-number`. The CPU must support 64-bit architecture. Intel CPUs must also support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT) and AMD CPUs must also support AMD Virtualization Technology (AMD-V).
2. If your CPU supports installing a 64-bit guest OS, select the 64-bit guest OS from the list in VMware. If that 64-bit guest OS is not supported on your host, the following warning message will appear:

   ```
   64-bit guest operating systems are not supported by this host and will not run.
   ```

By default, VMware Workstation will use Network Address Translation (NAT) to provide your virtual machine with network connectivity. For wifi connect the wireless network on the host operating system, and define a bridged or NAT connection in the VMware Workstation networking configuration.